# Tag for PasswordBox in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create PasswordBox with disappearing tag JUST in XAML.

The tag should fade when you type, and appear when a password is empty.

For TextBox I used MultiTrigger with the follow condition: Text == "". But for PasswordBox content is inaccessible

It's possible to realize without .cs files?

Comment: JUST in XAML can include cs code as you can write code directly in xaml. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42980/How-to-Embed-a-Csharp-Code-into-an-XAML-File

Comment: Can you provide xaml code you used for the textbox?